# Cant seem to set text in Event Handler

Tags: java, event-handling

I am fairly new to Java so I am probably missing something fundamental here but here goes.

I have a GUI with a button and I want to click on it, change the text in a window to something then perform a task

```
        connectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    databaseConnectWindow.setText("Connecting...");
                    connectToDatabase();
                 }
        });
```

But with the code above the text in databaseConnectWindow does not change until after conectToDatabse has finished.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a SwingWorker for a background thread so you don't lock the GUI thread otherwise known as the event dispatch thread or EDT. For more on this, please check out [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: +1 for the tutorial link which explains the problem in more detail.

Comment: Dito.. just what I was looking for.

Comment: Would this be so bad?...Runnable doWorkRunnable = new Runnable() { public void run() { connectToDatabase(); }};
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doWorkRunnable);

Comment: @Scott: that would be terrible as it would queue the task that you want done off of the EDT ***on*** the EDT -- the exact opposite of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I see that I still have a bit of reading ahead! On the plus side it did allow the text on my status window to update!

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `connectToDatabase()` in the UI thread.
The UI isn't able to update until the UI thread is free.

You should connect to the database on a background thread.